# Is there any way of viewing large ppsx files in browser

Tags: html, iframe

I want to display large ppsx file in browser without downloading. Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a plugin that knows how to interpret a ppsx file in the browser.

When the server pushes the file to you, it tells the browser the file type. It can also tell the browser to save the file instead of displaying it. In the second case I am not sure that you can stop it saving the file. In the first case if the browser doesn't have suitable plugin then it will save as a file.